# View raw image data in firefox without reloading

Tags: firefox, images

I'm developing a photo gallery in PHP. When a gallery page is requested for the first time, the PHP script resizes the JPEG's into thumbnails and stores them in a cache folder; any subsequent requests, the thumbnails are taken straight from there.

I'm finding that very occasionally, say 1 in 100 times, thumbnails are being displayed as "broken" images, I presume the PHP code is outputting some error message which is corrupting the image data. It's not that the source JPEG is missing or corrupt: if I reload the page it displays fine.

Is there any way in Firefox of seeing the raw image data, without reloading it from the server, to open it in (eg.) Notepad and see any error messages in its content? If I right-click the image and save it to disk, it re-requests it from the server and invariably I get a valid image that time.

Answer (score 1):

Open up the **Inspector** (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>). Go to the **Network** tab and select **Images**. You will have to refresh the page but the next time you refresh, this list will populate with the images retrieved on the page. You may want to refresh the cache as well (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> / <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>). Refresh until you can find the broken image you want to see the data for, right click, select **Copy Response**, and paste it to your text editor.